# Why do I have an extra <ul> within an <li> tag?

Tags: php, html, recursion

If I have a table of data (describing a tree structure) loaded into an array ($data) like below:

```
----------------------
| id | name | parent |
----------------------
| 1  | Jack | 0      | //this is the root/top level of tree
| 2  | ...  | 1      | //name column is irrelevant to problem
| 3  | ...  | 1      |
| 4  | ...  | 2      |
| 5  | ...  | 2      |
| 6  | ...  | 2      |
| 7  | ...  | 5      |
| 8  | ...  | 6      |
| 9  | ...  | 4      |
| 10 | ...  | 9      |
----------------------
```

And I want to generate a ul/li html tree using recursion, like below:

```
public function get_tree($data, $parent, $depth){
if ($depth > 1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
$tree = '<ul>';
for($i=0, $ni=count($data); $i < $ni; $i++) {
    if($data[$i]['parent'] == $parent){
        $tree .= '<li>';
        $tree .= '<span>' . $data[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        $tree .= $this->get_tree($data, $data[$i]['id'], $depth+1);
        $tree .= '</li>';
    }
}
$tree .= '</ul>';
return $tree;
}
```

For some reason I get an extra ul after each li. How do I fix this?

Comment: because you're calling the function recursively, and each time you're adding  `<ul>` before you ever get to the closing `</ul>`. There's also no closing `</li>` anywhere, and as you just added it, is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: Can you share a sample input `$data` and the output it produces?

Comment: Whatever that's supposed to be, add it to your question with proper formatting

Comment: I'm also not understanding what the problem here is, as far as i can tell everything is as it should be. Using your test case it appears that all elements appear under the correct parent and everything seems fine

Comment: instead of <li><span>23</span><ul></ul></li>, it should be just <li><span>23</span></li> and I know it's due to the recursion

Comment: You've just got an empty unorder list. There isn't any problem with it, unless you want to add some other check to make sure you don't get it. It doesn't hurt anything though, and only happens at the end of each call.

Comment: it's actually a problem because i'm using some CSS to generate a visual tree, and it ends up drawing an extra branch to nothing because of the empty ul

Comment: Gotchya. To fix it simpy move your `<ul></ul>`s inside of your if statement within the for loop. I'll post an answer and you can see if it gives what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_tree($data, $parent, $depth){
    if ($depth > 1000) return '';
    $tree = str_pad(' ',$depth);
    for($i=0, $ni=count($data); $i < $ni; $i++) {
        if($data[$i]['parent'] == $parent){
            $tree .= '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
            $tree .= str_pad(' ',$depth+2);
            $tree .= '<li>';
            $tree .= '<span>' . $data[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
            $tree .= '</li>'.PHP_EOL;
            $tree .= get_tree($data, $data[$i]['id'], $depth+1);
            $tree .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    $tree .= str_pad(' ',$depth);
    return $tree;
}
```

I only added the padding and EOLs so that on a simple test, you can easily see the tree

- one
  - two
    - four
      - nine
        - ten

- five
  - seven

- six
  - eight

- three

```
 <ul>
  <li><span>one</span></li>
 <ul>
   <li><span>two</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li><span>four</span></li>
   <ul>
     <li><span>nine</span></li>
    <ul>
      <li><span>ten</span></li>
          </ul>
    </ul>
   </ul>
<ul>
    <li><span>five</span></li>
   <ul>
     <li><span>seven</span></li>
        </ul>
   </ul>
<ul>
    <li><span>six</span></li>
   <ul>
     <li><span>eight</span></li>
        </ul>
   </ul>
  </ul>
<ul>
   <li><span>three</span></li>
    </ul>
 </ul>
```

Comment: that collapsed my tree to just the first level

Comment: Shouldn't, works fine here. Notice though that my function is not in a class. If you're just copy pasting my code, you'll need to edit it a bit, such as adding `$this->` before the recursive call within the function

Answer (score 1):

Because you're generating `<ul>` inside your recursive function. You need to do the `<ul>` and `</ul>` parts either on the outside or have the function check if it is the first call of it self and the last call of itself (to do the `</ul>`)

Comment: how would you test for the last call of itself? (i'm assuming the first call check would be if $depth == 0...?

Comment: I was sitting here thinking about that, you could capture the result of the subsequent get_tree requests before appending the result to your $tree and at the end of the $tree concatenation check if the get_tree returned '', null, or what ever and add the </ul>